# Can I use a std::fstream with UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, fstream, utf-16

The question came from using `std::wfstream` which uses `wchar_t` as the character type, i.e. it is `std::basic_fstream<wchar_t>`.

However `wchar_t` is ...odd. Particularly on Windows it is 2 bytes. So for portability it would be better to use `char16_t`, i.e. `std::basic_fstream<char16_t>`.
The underlying filebuf object needs a codecvt-facet for conversion between `char` and the character type. So for files encoded as UTF-8 [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) seems to be a good fit. One might even expect that the default `std::codecvt<char16_t, char, ...>` behaves like that, at least with an UTF-8 (C-)locale (an earlier C++ standard actually mandated that it "converts between the UTF-16 and UTF-8 encoding schemes" but can't find it in the current standard)

Except this is seemingly not possible according to [the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/locale.codecvt.virtuals#4). Summary:

> Informally, this means that basic_­filebuf assumes that the mappings from internal to external characters is 1 to N: that a codecvt facet that is used by basic_­filebuf can translate characters one internal character at a time.

This doesn't hold for UTF-16 where surrogate pairs (especially for codepoints above U+FFFF) need 2 internal characters.

Furthermore [as of C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) the `std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` is deprecated but

> All file I/O operations performed through `std::basic_fstream<CharT>` use the `std::codecvt<CharT, char, std::mbstate_t>` facet of the locale imbued in the stream.

So it seems that `std::basic_fstream<char16_t>` doesn't work as encoding to/from (all) UTF-16 strings is not possible/allowed.

So is the following correct?

- Decoding an UTF-8 encoded file with `std::wfstream` may fail when there is a codepoint above U+FFFF (Fails on Windows, Succeeds on Linux where `wchar_t` is 32 bit)
- Decoding such a file in a portable manner isn't possible (`std::codecvt<CharT, char,...>` used in a filebuf must not be able to do that for UTF-16, `std::codecvt<char32_t, char, ...>` is deprecated in C++20)

And questions:

- Isn't that a defect in the standard? I mean it seems to be a completely reasonable thing to read an UTF-8 encoded file into "wide(r)" strings
- Why is that single-character assumption there at all?
- What would break if one ignores that? Especially regarding existing implementations (w.g. MSVC STL, libstdc++, libc++)

Comment: Unhelpful comment - C++ does not do Unicode use [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) or another library.  It's been attempted (in the Standard) and as you say it doesn't currently work.  There seems to be no urgency at the Standard level to fix it.

Comment: "another library"... So basically some other implementation of the `basic_fstream` classes? Not really great ;-)

Comment: `std::basic_fstream` currently only has specializations for `char` and `wchar_t`, not for `char16_t`. On Windows, `wchar_t`-based APIs handle UTF-16 w/ surrogates just fine, and `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>` will handle UTF-16 surrogates correctly as expected when reading data to `std::wstring`.

Comment: I open UTF-16 files with `std::fstream`, and do my own conversion from UTF-16 (file representation) to UTF-8 (internal format I use, held in a `std::string`).  I prefer working with UTF-8 files, but that's not always an option.  C++ has considerable room for improvement regarding Unicode.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not exactly. As of currently `wfstream` will decode to UCS-2 not UTF-16, so those high codepoints will make the decoding fail and using a custom `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, ...>` which would decode to UTF-16 is disallowed to be used in a `basic_filebuf` by the standard. Hence the question why. And yes reading the file to a `string` and then do a conversion to a UTF-16 encoded `wstring` afterwards is an option but not great either

Comment: @Flamefire `std::wfstream` itself has no concept of encodings, it is the `codecvt` of the imbue'd `std::locale` that handles the encoding. `std::codecvt_utf8` will convert UTF-8 to UCS-2 or UTF-16 depending on implementation, `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` will convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 exclusively. But you are right that `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` can't be used with `std::basic_filebuf` and thus with `std::wfstream` (which I did not claim it could). But it can be used with `std::wstring_convert`.

Comment: Note: ICU is the reference library for Unicode handling. Then there are language bindings (so to use natively, but that is not the focus). If you need to do something serious with Unicode (and not just black box of string) you just need it. Splitting strings? You need it (do not split string at random codepoints, they may just be combining marks). Upcase/Lowercase? ICU is the only really good library (especially if you use Turkish). -- In any case, UTF-16 may need 2 coding units, but a grapheme may need many code points, so working UCS-2 or UTF-16 is similar, until you get in deep semantic.